# Запятая: "Вас и так записывают (,) куда только можно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Какой вариант правильный и почему?

1. Вас и так записывают, куда только можно.
2. Вас и так записывают куда только можно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

***Вас и так записывают куда только можно.***

Это цельное по смыслу выражение, имеющее  значение одного слова ― ***везде, всюду***. 
http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/50.htm

**Примеры:**

Я уже было согрелся и снова замерз ― ноги в ботинках заледенели, снег набился **куда только можно**. [Дина Сабитова. Где нет зимы (2011)]

Сравнить:

Я уже **всюду, куда только можно,** писал, что с таким инжектором я работать больше не могу. [В. Т. Шаламов. Колымские рассказы (1954-1961

Это придаточное предложение, относится к опорному наречию ***всюду.***